# How MongoDB Handles $addFields on Array Elements that Do Not Exist

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If I use `$addFields` as an aggregation stage for an element that doesn't actually exist, how will Mongo handle that?

I ask because, in my data, for one particular field that is an array, some documents have 1 array element, and others have 2 or 3 (so position 0, 1, and 2).

So if I do this:

```
$addFields : {
    secondAgency: {$arrayElemAt:["$agency", 1]},
}
```

How will Mongo handle documents where there is no element in position 1 of the agency array? Is there a way I could handle this with a conditional check -- to only include this field if there is an array element in position 1 of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll simply ignore the value and won't add such field. To add a default value, use `$ifNull`:

```
db.getCollection('x').aggregate([
    {$addFields: {
        secondAgency1:            {$arrayElemAt: ["$agency", 1]},
        secondAgency2: {$ifNull: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$agency", 1]}, "DEFAULT"]}
    }}
])
```